# How to require from required file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql

I need to require bar from bar.js and foo from foo.js in each file.

How I can do it?

foo.js

```
const bar = require('./bar');
const foo = 'Hello';
console.log(`${foo} ${bar}!`);
module.exports = foo;
```

bar.js

```
const foo = require('./foo');
const bar = 'World';
console.log(`${foo} ${bar}!`);
module.exports = bar;
```

Main purpose is for have many to many GraphQL connection.

I want to require in rootQuery separate files with lets say postType.js and tagType.js. And I need to query posts from tags, and tags from posts.

Is it possible?

Comment: Sounds like a circular dependencies, are you sure this is the optimal way to do this?

Comment: andrew is right, circular dependencies should always be avoid, if you are in this situation it's a symptom that something is wrong in your code and maybe you need a little bit of refactoring.

Comment: Please read the node docs. They explain a lot. https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles node.js has built in mechanisms for handling this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible node.js has built in mechanisms for handling just this sort circular `require()` calls. Please read the node documentation. https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

Comment: Thanks, it's seems like a good answer.

Anyway with GraphQL I fixed this with getting post by tag not in tags but in post type with args for posts.